# Double bibliography, at the end and for any chapters

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

Hi guys I've many difficult to do a chapter bibliography.
In the attachment there are a pdf after compile and the source.
I would like to have a bibliography for each chapter, and a final as well as I have already.
Can you help me?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/main1.pdf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/questions.rar

Minimal Example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Foo}
Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Bar}
Some text \cite{hashemian}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}


\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you're starting your project, you should consider `biblatex`, which has facilities for multiple bibliographies built in.

Comment: Thanks. I'm usig biblatex, but I did not understand how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Using `biblatex`, and its package option `refsegment=chapter`, you can add a command like this at the end of each chapter

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=N]
```

where N has to be set to the chapter number. The option `heading=subbibliography` just makes this bibliography a section-level one.

A bare `\printbibliography` should give you a global, chapter-level, bibliography.

That's what I used in May 2013, so I'm guessing it was with `biblatex` version 2.5 or 2.6. Documentation of version 2.8 (p. 49) seems to indicate this still works.

On your example, this works as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Foo}
Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\thechapter]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Bar}
Some text \cite{hashemian}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\thechapter]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @tohecz, I was just starting to put together this example.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works almost as well, in fact I have 2 problems (the problem I have it because my text is not minimal example but it is plugged into a template for thesis): 
1) In the bibliography for each chapter, the header has the same number of the previous section [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/section.jpg)
2) is inserted into the chapter number in the bibliography. how can I do? [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/chapter.jpg)

Comment: I think it would be best to launch a new question, complete with MWE. It's a bit difficult to answer this question just from looking at your screen captures, for all I know you might have redefined sectioning commands in the preamble.